# Trouble with plesk VPS issue hosting magento. #sql_1ed7_0.MYD in /tmp brings down server

Tags: mysql, apache, magento, plesk, server

Hope someone can help! I keep getting these files created in /tmp which creates error below when trying to access web or even the plesk panel until I go in via SSH or FTP and manually delete it (#sql_1ed7_0.MYD):

```
ERROR: Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_1ed7_0.MYD' (Errcode: 17) (Pdo.php:234)
```

There is nothing in any of the MySQL logs, changed the mysql tmp directory in my.cnf to home/mysqltmp and still happens so doesnt look that's the issue. I think its possible to do with httpd.conf, here is the logs around when it happens in the apache error_log:

```
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:21 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Store/Collection.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15876)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:21 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Sns/Quickview/Helper/Data.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15876)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:22 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:22 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Website.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15872)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:22 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Image.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15869)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:22 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Tree.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15858)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:22 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15876)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:22 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15872)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:22 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15856)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:22 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category/Attribute/Backend/Image.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15872)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:22 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Block/Currency.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15872)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:22 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15872)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:22 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/sns_kalins/template/directory/currency.phtml - Too many open files in system (pid 15856)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:22 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Config.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15872)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:23 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Sns/Ajaxcart/Helper/Core/Url.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15856)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:23 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Ddl/Table.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15876)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:23 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Event/Observer.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15876)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:23 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Data.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15876)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:23 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15869)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:24 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Data.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15876)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:24 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Data.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15874)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:24 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15874)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:24 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Cache/Core.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15876)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:24 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Base.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15856)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:24 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Store/Group/Collection.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15876)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:24 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Abstract.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15874)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:24 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php - Too many open files in system (pid 15869)
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:42 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Fri Nov 28 16:09:52 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Fri Nov 28 17:25:51 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Nov 28 17:25:53 2014] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Nov 28 17:25:54 2014] [warn] RSA server certificate
[Fri Nov 28 17:25:55 2014] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 256 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Fri Nov 28 17:25:55 2014] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
```

Completely at a loss....getting no where with Google :(  Just installed a full page cache module in magento which I think is the source of the cache file errors in the log but that was installed after this issue started.

Don't want to have to keep babysitting the server to delete this file again and again.

Worth noting there is no problems with the permissions of the /tmp directory (1777), however the file that's created has permissions of 644 and as soon as I delete it everything's back up.

Comment: Do you have free HDD space on your server ?

Comment: Yeah plenty just looking at server info in plesk 43gb free. Cpu last 15min sitting at 3.23 and ram 15.1%

Comment: This message "Too many open files in system" should be  the cause of the problem... I found this about that: http://forum.sp.parallels.com/threads/error-trying-to-open-horde-blank-page-shown.97384/

Answer (score 3):

It seems what issue not in Magento. Your apache log said: Too many open files in system.

You need to increase the maximum number of allowed open file descriptors. For doing this find Apache init script and add next line in it:

```
ulimit -n 65536
```

Usually, Apache init script placed in /etc/init.d/apache2 or /etc/init.d/httpd paths.

As result it will looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: apache2
# Required-Start: $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Required-Stop: $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# X-Interactive: true
# Short-Description: Start/stop apache2 web server ### END INIT INFO
set -e
ulimit -n 65536
```

After that restart Apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Do you think that would cause he temp file to be created and then messed up? Need to go further back in the logs as I think the to many files happened after installing the full page cache module which was after this issue started at the start of the week so could be a seperate issue totally

Comment: I think what mysql just can't write to created file, because it should open file for writing but can't do it due to files limit. "Too many open files in system" is first issue what should be fixed because this is  server-level issue, many services can working unstable or don't working at all with producing strange and messy messages in logs.

Comment: Yeah, magento has a nice habit of filling logs. What's a safe limit for the unlimit value?

Comment: 65536 should be ok. I use it on my servers. Also please look at this tips: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/linux-postinstallation.html

Comment: Perfect I will try this out and see how it goes!

Comment: Happened again this morning so I have icreased the max open files by adding * soft nofile 65536 and * hard nofile 65536 lines to limits.conf.

Comment: Also getting these lines in the log around when it happens 
'[Mon Dec 01 03:10:29 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process'
'[Mon Dec 01 04:02:05 2014] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart'
'[Mon Dec 01 04:02:06 2014] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 256 max processes and 0 max threads.'
'[Mon Dec 01 04:02:06 2014] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp '

Comment: Also added the ulimit -n 65536 to /etc/init.d/httpd. Running comand ulimit -n now returns 6553, previously was 1024

Comment: "Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process" is another issue. You don't have enough RAM to cover all the processes and Apache tries to spawn during peak load. So you need to verify whether you're at peak load or not. Some process 'eat' all of your memory. You can check memory usage in Home > Server Health > Memory in Plesk panel. What occurs with memory usage when you open site in browser?

Comment: Ahh It went again ,was OK for 2 days...

The file in the tmp directory same as first post, had to manually delete it and everythings back online. The file was created at 06:18am this morning.

Logs around that time (still getting a few to many open file errors)

[Thu Dec 04 06:17:48 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 25453

Cant post it all here so will post as an answer..

Answer (score 0):

Happened again, logs when the file was created (quite a lot)

**

```
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:11 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:21 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:31 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:32 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Output.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25375)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:34 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/allansfurniture.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Abstract.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25375)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:34 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:34 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:34 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:34 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:34 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Entity/Attribute/Option/Collection.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25375)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Design.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25378)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/PaypalUk/Block/Express/Shortcut.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25378)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Flat.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25378)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25379)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:35 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run fastcgi
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process production error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process \xf0Z\xa8\x90\xff\xff\xff\x7f\xd8\x84\xf5\x80e\x7f error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:36 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process \xf0Z\xa8\x90\xff\xff\xff\x7f\xd8\x84\xf5\x80e\x7f error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:37 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process \xf0Z\xa8\x90\xff\xff\xff\x7f\xd8\x84\xf5\x80e\x7f error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process \xf0Z\xa8\x90\xff\xff\xff\x7f\xd8\x84\xf5\x80e\x7f error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:38 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Url.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25349)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:39 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Locale/Math/PhpMath.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25380)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:39 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:39 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process \xf0Z\xa8\x90\xff\xff\xff\x7f\xd8\x84\xf5\x80e\x7f error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:39 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Resource/Stock/Status.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25380)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:40 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Wrapper.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25374)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:41 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/allansfurniture.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Element.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25374)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:41 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:42 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25374)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25349)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 25440
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 25443
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 25444
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process \xf0Z\xa8\x90\xff\xff\xff\x7f\xd8\x84\xf5\x80e\x7f error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:43 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Event/Collection.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25379)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25379)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25373)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/allansfurniture.com/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Event/Collection.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25357)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process \xf0Z\xa8\x90\xff\xff\xff\x7f\xd8\x84\xf5\x80e\x7f error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run \x04
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process  resuming normal operations error
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25357)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25378)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25375)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:44 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25378)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:45 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Ddl/Table.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25375)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:45 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Config.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25375)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:45 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Version.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25375)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:46 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/index.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25378)
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:48 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 25453
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:48 2014] [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process 25456
[Thu Dec 04 06:17:51 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:01 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:05 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:05 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper error
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:11 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:21 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:21 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Helper/Data.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25472)
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:21 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Exception.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25472)
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:27 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25472)
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:31 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:41 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:50 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:50 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper error
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:51 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: fork: Unable to fork new process
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:51 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:51 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper error
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:52 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:52 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper error
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:53 2014] [warn-phpd] mmap cache can't open /var/www/vhosts/site/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Validate/Interface.php - Too many open files in system (pid 25477)
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:54 2014] [error] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: can't run /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper
[Thu Dec 04 06:18:54 2014] [warn] (12)Cannot allocate memory: mod_fcgid: spawn process /var/www/cgi-bin/cgi_wrapper/cgi_wrapper error
```

**

Comment: It seems what too many process started on server. As example, too many sites placed on server (300-400 or more). Each site operate with Apache/PHP/MySQL which have own log files, etc. Can you provide more details about your hosting type, CPU and Memory? (do you use http://www.1und1.de ? :)

Comment: Yeah it's 1and1 but in the UK. The server has 3 cpu cores to memory and 2GB ram with 4GB available on demand. Only hosts this one magento site.

Comment: Ran perfectly until rolling over to the new magento template! Can't see why a template would hog so much resources. The new template is a lot lot slower than before which is why the full page cache had to go on

Comment: Can you show result of next command: cat /proc/user_beancounters

Comment: Posted as answer below

Comment: About slow Magento template: I saw similar issue few weeks ago, problems was in header menu (it produce 600 sql queries for building menu). For checking whats going on with new template you can use some free developer toolbar for Magento on your dev site copy, for example, mine :) http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/tb-developer-toolbar.html

Comment: I will have a look in to this. Do you have a copy of the module on github or anything that can be installed via ftp? Dont have a dev copy of the site anymore but can create a copy in plesk. Chances are running 2 will bring the box down more often if there is an issue. Can you see anything out of place from command result above?

Comment: Extension don't placed on github yet (shame on me). You can install it via Magento Connect manager or extract and copy folders via ftp. You also can download it directly via Freegento: http://freegento.com/magento-extensions/tb_develop-1.0.5.tgz

Answer (score 0):

Result from command cat /proc/user_beancounters

```
   uid  resource                     held              maxheld                                       
barrier                limit              failcnt
 78271296:  kmemsize                 35731312             38395904             4                         
1943040             50331648                 1626
            lockedpages                     0                    0                                       
    512                  512                    0
            privvmpages                301647               306222                                       
1048576              1153433                    0
            shmpages                    26837                26837                                       
  32768                32768                    0
            dummy                           0                    0  922337203685                         
4775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            numproc                        94                  162                                       
    256                  256                    0
            physpages                  124571               132416                                       
1048576              1048576                    0
            vmguarpages                     0                    0                                       
 524288               524288                    0
            oomguarpages                87348                87348                                       
 524288               524288                    0
            numtcpsock                     23                   24                                       
    720                  720                    0
            numflock                       27                   28                                       
    376                  413                    0
            numpty                          1                    1                                       
     32                   32                    0
            numsiginfo                      0                   54                                       
    512                  512                    0
            tcpsndbuf                  348800               366240                                       
3440640              5406720              8896551
            tcprcvbuf                  360448               376832                                       
3440640              5406720                    0
            othersockbuf               180336               192920                                       
2252160              4194304                    0
            dgramrcvbuf                     0                    0                                       
 524288               576716                    0
            numothersock                  129                  133                                       
    720                  720                    0
            dcachesize               11533698             11533940             1                         
0485760             11534336                    0
            numfile                      2985                 3135                                       
   8192                 8192                    0
            dummy                           0                    0  922337203685                         
4775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            dummy                           0                    0  922337203685                         
4775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            dummy                           0                    0  922337203685                         
4775807  9223372036854775807                    0
            numiptent                      21                   21                                       
    200                  205                    0
```

Comment: Please look at this: http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/1354  then look on your failcount column.  If it has values more than zero, make sense to change Virtuozzo (openVZ) settings.

Comment: its hard to tell what colum is failcnt in the way it returns. From what it looks like failcnt is all 0 apart from kmemsize which has 1626

Comment: how would i chek/ammend the relevant settings for this?

Comment: kmemsize=1626, tcpsndbuf=8896551. kmemsize - The size of unswappable kernel memory allocated for the internal kernel structures for the processes of a particular VE.
tcpsndbuf - The total size of send buffers for TCP sockets, i.e. the ammount of kernel memory allocated for the data sent from an application to a TCP socket, but not acknowledged by the remote side yet. I'm not sure what you have access to this openVZ settings, please ask hosting support for this (try to check /etc/vz/vz.conf).

Comment: Is this a red flag that something needs increased?

Comment: Also just installed your module and after clearing cache I just get a 404 Not found on the settings page system>configuration>tb developer toolbar

Comment: Yes, if you see non-zero values in the failcnt column that means something is wrong.

Comment: About module, just logout from admin area and login again.

Comment: Yep got it now, where should I see the result? Enabled with my IP address in the client area

Comment: Clear the site cache, then click on yellow button on top right on page and look at Dashboard->Code Profiler and Models->SQL Profiles. This is main sections for analyzing. Other sections (like Layout, Blocks) and tabs (like Models->Collections) help you to find details.

Comment: Ah ok. I will try and have a look at this tonight. What sort of things should I be looking out for that are red flags?

Comment: Dashboard->Code Profiler - look at Time column. If some cells have more than 1 sec, something is not optimized. Block->Rewrites - look at Status column.
Models->Models - look at Calls column, normal value is less than 50. Models->Collections, here you can find repeated collections with the same queries (normal total qty is ~100). Models->SQL Profiler, look at total qty of qeries and Time column, if query time is more than 1 sec - make sense to optmize it. This is very short descritpion, just note what all information on sections/tabs is what Magento to do for load current page. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok. On the frontend there are a few above 1sec. Mage::dispatch::routers_match is 6.859020 and layout/DB_update: default 6sec, layout_update: MAP_popup 6sec, layout_update CMS page 6sec, layout/db_update: THEME_frontend_default_sns_kalins also 6sec and a few other all look theme related. So looking like something in This template is the bottleneck - with fully age cache turned off the loading time on the theme is terrible, before the site was super fast

Comment: Also in the models for catalog_model_category on the homepage is 297 - is this the way the template loads things?

Comment: Yes, some template is bottleneck (or some Block which this template use). Items like Mage::dispatch::routers_match show summary time for included blocks. Scroll down and find one or few *.phtml files which have abnormal time. In most cases you find one template which time=5-6 sec. Then go to app/design/frontend/default/sns/kalins/this_template_file.phtml and analyze the source code. Common issue: creation objects, load collections inside some foreach cycle.

Comment: 'catalog_model_category' model on home page used for generation menu with categories. Find menu template and check is it really call it 297 times? I beleive decrease calls for build nestend menu structure is possible. Magento can fly but it needs to be cleaned feathers.

Comment: It appears mainmenu.phtml is taking 4.7sec and using 3.25MB of memory and header.phtml is taking 4.8sec using 5.25MB of memory. The only other phtml file listed with a long time is the 2colul-left template file which is 6sec

Comment: Block on the homepage to show featured products is taking 1.5 sec but using 12.5MB memory

Comment: I have enabled to use flat category and that has made quite a difference although if I enable to use flat products the homepage featured products block in the theme looses its images and just shows the magento placeholder. Even after clearing every cache and a re index

Comment: Open Layouts->Result Layout, find blocks which add mainmenu.phtml, header.phtml and 2column-left.phtml and check do they have sub-blocks. If yes, find their template names and check their load time in Dashboard->Code Profiler. After that analyze it too. You also can compare what to do this templates in previous "fast" theme.

Comment: Enabling FLAT mode for product/categories is good idea, but I can't say exactly what going wrong with it without debugging. I think you need Magento developer to optimize templates and solve other issues.